# Question about resumes and LinkedIn for employers

Tags: hiring-process, resume, linkedin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listing LinkedIn profile as a full CV - looks lazy, or convenient for recruiters?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1154/listing-linkedin-profile-as-a-full-cv-looks-lazy-or-convenient-for-recruiters)

Do you think that it's lazy or unprofessional to use LinkedIn to make a resume? (I'm talking about the PDF that you can get from the profile page.)

How would you feel if someone submitted a resume that was generated using LinkedIn?